# performing ajax action from default function throws 'cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am receiving a 'cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' error when executing an ajax call from the default action on a controller.

My route definition is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have an MVC 5 memecontroller with the following get functions:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> getmeme(string parameter)
{
    if (parameter.Equals("improvise"))
    {
        var absolutelyBarbaric = new string[]{ "adapt ", "improvise ", "overcome"};
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(absolutelyBarbaric, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("to lazy for other examples");
}
```

the html page adapt.htmlcs is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var options = {
            url: 'getmeme?parameter=improvise'
          };
          $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $('#memes');
            $target.replaceWith(data);
          });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="memes">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I navigate to **http://localhost:1234/meme/index**, the page loads as normal, with the ajax function calling normally. When i navigate to **http://localhost:1234/meme** i can see that the index function is called in the debugger, but the ajax call throws an 'cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' error. Why is this happening, and more importantly, how can i prevent it?

EDIT:
removed use of the ViewBag, since it had no function here

Comment: this is a binding issue, maybe related to the ViewBag, but your code here seems to poor to reproduce the issue

Comment: the question is confusing, you're showing the code for adapt.cshtml but you're telling us that you're getting error on the `/meme ` page and you're not showing the meme view or action

Comment: i can reproduce the error with this code. I tested before posting. When i run the full address, i get displayed on my monitor 'adapt improvise overcome'. The error occurs in the ajax call